# How can I animate a UIView Container to decrease its height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am looking to animate the size of my UIView Container at the same time my ad appears at the bottom. I have the ad slide up from the bottom of the screen when it's ready. I want my UIView container to decrease that same amount of size as the ad slides up.

I created an outlet property for my container view within the top level UIViewController that it is embedded in.

My ad animation code:

```
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view
{
    NSLog(@"Received Ad");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                self.view.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height,
                                view.frame.size.width,
                                view.frame.size.height);



        // This is where I think I would need to animate the container view.

    }];
}
```

How can I decrease the size of my container view to match that of the ad? I need the container to stay in the same spot and everything, but some height needs to be taken off of the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simple: just animate your container frame in the same block as you are animating your banner view up. It will be something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {

    view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                            self.view.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height,
                            view.frame.size.width,
                            view.frame.size.height);



     self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake( self.containerView.frame.origin.x,
                            self.containerView.frame.origin.y,
                            self.containerView.frame.size.width,
                            self.containerView.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height);
}];
```

This piece of code will decrease your containerView as the same height of your banner and at the same time. You can change/adapt as you want.

Edit: if you are using autolayout, you should create a IBOutlet for the constraint and animate it, and not the frame itself.

Comment: That was literally the exact code that I had written there, but it didn't do anything at all. There were no changes to the container view. Any ideas as to why that could happen?

Comment: I actually just did another test with it and the view 'pops' to the correct frame that we specified, but then it immediately 'pops' back to the way it was. So essentially it is executing the statement and then immediately changing back

Comment: This piece of code for sure only shrinks the cointainerView frame. If its changing back, the problem is somewhere else. Look in your code where you might be changing the frame of this view, or something like this

Comment: I figured out that I was needing to change the constraint for the container rather than the actual size of the view. Using autolayout made it 'pop' back to its original state.

Comment: Yes, if you are using autolayout, you should create a IBOutlet for the constraint and animate it, and not the frame itself.